# How to center colls in row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to divide the browser window into two fluid rows so that regardless of size, they are stretched across the screen. In the first row i need to add different columns which should be centered automatically. Basically it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I can not center cols in first row and rows are not stretch to the browser height. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @oGeez this is `twitter-bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use offset to center div

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can change padding for ajust space between blocs.

See on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JtzE6/

Comment: thanks, may be you also know how to set rows that the use full browser space? Like red squares in the picture...

Comment: @Kin : for that, if IE8+ is target then, look for `display:table` and `display:table-cell` :)

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the Alignment Classes on twitter bootstrap documentation ([Twitter Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis)). You should be able to apply these to any element tag in html. It worked for me.. Hope this helps..