# How to center my divs with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center my divs with bootstrap

html

```
 <div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid row">
        <div id="left" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            //stuff
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            //stuff
        </div>
    </div>
```

it shows

```
 ----------------------------
|                            |
||left  | |       right      |
||      | |                  |
||      | |                  |
|
|
```

I want to have

```
 ----------------------------
|
|     |left|  |  right  |
|     |    |  |         | 
|
|
```

with `Left` and `Right` divs centered within `wrapper` all the time.

What is the best way to do this with bootstrap class only?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382970/how-to-center-a-div-with-bootstrap

Comment: link is to the old version, should refer to the new version code

Comment: You could use offsets

Comment: The question that's been marked as duplicate doesn't address bootstrap and therefore isn't a correct answer.

Comment: There's also the issue of whether or not `<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid row">` is correct. Should `.container` and `.row` be used in one element together?

Comment: the duplcated question is the css way instead of bootstrap way.

Comment: It still requires a CSS change, but it needs to do so in context of boostrap's css.

Comment: You have answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156822/how-to-center-colls-in-row-in-bootstrap/

Comment: I apologize for the close vote, I've reopened your question now, the link was incorrect... am sorry for that

Comment: But still your question is a duplicate, see the related questions column on the right hand side, it will provide you the answers

Comment: Replace "container-fluid row" by "container"

Answer (score 1):

like this by using offset

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">this div</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">the other div</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/m4mREVEntv#